# How to print individual values of an object?

Tags: python, list, object

I have a list that I've filled with objects. I'm able to print an entire object by using:

```
print str(vars(theList[0]))
```

or in a loop:

```
i = 0
for objects in theList:

     print str(vars(theList[i]))
     i+=1
```

What if I only want one of the values in the object and not the entire object.

Edit trying to clarify the question further:
Lets' say I have a list of ten objects with name, age, address, and phone number. What if I want index 1 object's name only and not the entire contents of the object at index one. That is the goal.

```
print str(vars(theList[0].itemOne))
```

The above gives me `TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute`

I found another question that suggested using `dic` instead of `vars` but that didn't work. It only printed a long list:

`['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']`

Comment: To print the value of the first item in the list just do print(listName[0])            Edit: I think whats actually happening is there are lists inside lists, so if you want the first item of the first item of a list your need to do print(listName[0][0])

Comment: No, as I said, the list is a list of objects and is NOT a list inside a list so `print(listName[0][0])` doesn't work. Trying as you suggest throws this error: `object does not support indexing`  Also as stated, I know how to get a value from the list. What I'm asking is how can I only print certain items from the object and not the entire contents of the object.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your post properly. Not a duplicate and my answer wouldn't work

Comment: I had actually already looked at that thread and tried what was suggested.

Comment: What is the type of the `theList[0]` object? If the type defines a `__str__` or `__repr__` method it can control how it is converted to a string and displayed. Otherwise, you'll have to write code to display its attributes yourself depending on what kind of thing it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for object in list_name:
    print(object)   # <--- the "body"
```

This is the for loop syntax. It executes the body of the for loop once for every item in the list, assigning the item to the name, here it is `object`.

Replace `list_name` with your list's name and `object` to the appropriate name.

Comment: Yes this works! I can do `print(object.object_Item)` and get the results I'm looking for.